# JTable not showing added entries in database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Im creating an inventory system for our project in school but I stumbled across a problem, I have two forms, when I click the add button in my firstform called mainform, a new form will show the addjframe form, I then put entries, but when I click the add button in the addjframe form the data is in my ms-access database, but my jtable is blank

I tried making my table public static so that it can be called on my second form

heres the code for for my table on the mainform

```
    public static void AddRowToJTable(Object[] dataRow)
    {
    DefaultTableModel dtm ;
    dtm= (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    dtm.addRow(dataRow);
    dtm.setRowCount(0);

    }
```

heres the code for my add button on the Addjframe form/second form

```
   private void btnaddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   String title = txttitle.getText();
   String author = txtauthor.getText();
   String date = txtdate.getText();
   String genre = txtgenre.getText();

   try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/elibrary1.accdb");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.execute("INSERT INTO libtable(Title,Author,Dateadded,Genre) VALUES ('"+title+"','"+author+"','"+date+"','"+genre+"')");
        String sql = "Select * from libtable";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            mainform.AddRowToJTable(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4)});
        }
    }


    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());


    }


}
```

It should show the entries on my jtable i dont know whats wrong with my code, ive been stuck on this for days, I dont receive any error messages, because the entries are being put in my ms-access database its just that it doesnt show on my jtable

Any help would be appreciated!

here's my first form the table is not showing anything when i click add on my second form

[image: here's my first form the table is not showing anything when i click add on my second form]

this is my second form to add data in the database

[image: this is my second form to add data in the database]
here is my ms-access database showing my recently entered data at the bottom

[image: here is my ms-access database showing my recently entered data at the bottom]

Comment: From your comments it would indicate that the query is coming back blank. Try writing the contents of `rs` to the console just so that you can verify if there is a result `System.out.println(rs.getString(1) +","+.getString(2))`.

Comment: thankyou for your response, what console? im very sorry for i am new to database

Comment: The java console, the same place where you see errors. This will be shown in whatever program you are using to write the java code, or if you use a terminal it will show up in the terminal window. Just add `System.out.println(rs.getString(1) +","+.getString(2));` inside your `while (rs.next()) {` statement.

Comment: thanks it worked! the data's are shown on my console, any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: Ok, so we know that you have data, then the issue is that the data is not getting to the current instance of the `mainform`. Make sure that when you create the `mainform` variable that it is actually referancing the current or a static instance of the form, rather than a new instance of mainform.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.